# SQL Server query tuning strategy

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm new to query tuning and have been using Brent Ozar's tools to identify costly stored procedures. This one triggered warnings for Parallel, Plan Warnings, Parameter Sniffing, Downlevel CE, Implicit Conversions, Trivial Plans, and Low Cost High CPU. I am in need of a strategy for attacking the query plan below:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1riejcjU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the estimated costs for the queries are accurate, there's only one you need to worry about, and it's easily fixed.

Remove the non-sargable, and unnecessary RTRIM, and add OPTION RECOMPILE to get a plan based on the actual parameters passed on each execution.  See the classic [Dynamic Search Conditions in TSQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for more info.

Change

```
SELECT @CustomerNumber = CustomerNumber
FROM DMVData dd
WHERE ((@PINNumber IS NULL) OR (dd.PINNumber = @PINNumber)) 
 AND ((@TagNumber IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(dd.PlateNumber) = @TagNumber))
 AND ((@VIN IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(dd.VIN) = @VIN))
 AND ((@DriversLicense IS NULL) OR (dd.DLNumberOne = @DriversLicense) OR (dd.DLNumberTwo = @DriversLicense))
 AND ((@Title IS NULL) OR (TitleNumber = @Title))
 AND ((@DOB IS NULL) OR (dd.DOBOne = @DOB) OR (dd.DOBTwo = @DOB))
```

to

```
SELECT @CustomerNumber = CustomerNumber
FROM DMVData dd
WHERE ((@PINNumber IS NULL) OR (dd.PINNumber = @PINNumber)) 
 AND ((@TagNumber IS NULL) OR (dd.PlateNumber = @TagNumber))
 AND ((@VIN IS NULL) OR (dd.VIN = @VIN))
 AND ((@DriversLicense IS NULL) OR (dd.DLNumberOne = @DriversLicense) OR (dd.DLNumberTwo = @DriversLicense))
 AND ((@Title IS NULL) OR (TitleNumber = @Title))
 AND ((@DOB IS NULL) OR (dd.DOBOne = @DOB) OR (dd.DOBTwo = @DOB))
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: From prod data it looks like the RTRIM is necessary. Thanks for suggesting OPTION (RECOMPILE).

Comment: Test it.  SQL Server ignores trailing spaces in equality comparisons on varchar and nvarchar types.  eg run `select 1 where 'a' = 'a  '`

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure contains 7 queries (statements) and almost each has an issue:

- Query1: Parameter sniffing, Trivial Plan
- Query2: Parallelism, Parameter sniffing
- Query3: Trivial Plan
- Query4: Implicit Conversion, Low cost + High CPU
- Query5: OK
- Query6: OK
- Query7: OK

  And Legacy CE for the whole procedure.